# How to get the second smallest eigenvalue of the laplacian with R?

Tags: r, matlab

I'm trying to use R to capture the second smallest eigenvalue of the Laplacian of a graph, but I just know how to do it in Matlab. I have searched in the web about it, but I just always find how to use the R-function "eigen"

Does somebody can tell me how to write such a code line, please?

In Matlab, for example, the line that I use to code is:

```
[~, D] = eigs(lap, 2, 'sa');    %getting the first two eigenvalues of laplacian (lap). 'sa' means Smallest Algebraic
lambda2 = D(2, 2);              %getting the second smallest eigenvalue
```

Thanks in advance for your helpful comments.

Comment: Please make it reproducible with small data and output.

Comment: See `?eigen`::Values. `eigen(lap)$values` is sorted in decreasing order...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A  = cbind(c(1,-1,0), c(-1,1,1), c(0.5,0.5,0.5))
ei = eigen(A)

ei$values[length(ei$value)-1]
```

gives second smallest eigenvalue of matrix A

Comment: Really thanks for your answer, It is what I need to know.